# How to remove an EventListener in a class method with multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove a document EventListener. I understand that the reference needs to be exactly the same, but somehow it is not working, even though it's using the same variable.

When I inspect the event listeners in the browser, I can see that they are not being removed. Why not?

```js
class CommentsBlock {

  constructor(container) {
    this._handleEvent;
    this._comments = container.querySelectorAll('[data-selector="comment"]');

    this._comments.forEach((comment) => {
      const deleteButton = comment.querySelector('[data-selector="delete-icon"]');
      deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => this.showDeleteDialog(event));

    });
  }


  showDeleteDialog(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    const comment = event.target.closest('[data-selector="comment"]');
    const dialog = comment.querySelector('[data-selector="dialog"]');

    this._handleEvent = this.hideDeleteDialog.bind(this, event, dialog)

    if (confirmDeleteDialog) {
      show(confirmDeleteDialog);

      document.addEventListener('click', this._handleEvent);
    }
  }

  hideDeleteDialog(event, dialog) {
    if (!dialog.contains(event.target)) {
      hide(dialog);

      // Not working
      document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleEvent)
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to store a reference to the bound function

Comment: Add some `console.log`s or alerts to see if `dialog.contains` ever true

Comment: @DanielA.White, thank you, i didn't really understand that bind() was creating a copy. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Theoretical explanation -**

The way code is written, this._handleEvent is shared across all delete buttons that you have on your screen.

So when you click on delete button, Due to this line `this._handleEvent = this.hideDeleteDialog.bind(this, event, dialog)` a copy of `hideDeleteDialog` function gets assigned to this._handleEvent and a click listener is added on document. All good till this point.

Now if you click same or different delete buttons X time then, each time new copy of `hideDeleteDialog` will be assigned to shared `this._handleEvent` i.e. it is being overriden each time any delete button is getting clicked and at same time new click listeners are being added on the document.

Now when you finally click somewhere on document then `hideDeleteDialog` will be called but at this point `this._handleEvent` is pointing to a copy of `hideDeleteDialog` created when you last clicked some delete button. Hence only last click listener added on document will be cleared but rest of the click listener will stay.

**Time to see some proofs -**

Below code is abstraction of code provided in question and it's enough to prove the case. Try clicking on delete button X times and you will see X number of console logs saying 'In showDeleteDialog', Now click on document somewhere and you will see `X-1` console logs saying `In hideDeleteDialog`.

This is because `hideDeleteDialog` is called X times, But then in first call `this._handleEvent` click listener gets removed successfully and in rest of the calls it tries to remove `this._handleEvent` listener but that don't exist anymore on document.

Hence you are seeing X-1 click listeners always attached to document.

**Potential solutions -**

Best way would be to clear the this._handleEvent click listener from the document before overriding it.

`OR`

Make this._handleEvent an array and append the listeners to it on click of delete button, So that you can clear all of them later.

```js
class CommentsBlock {

  constructor(container) {
    this._handleEvent;
    this._comments = container.querySelectorAll('[data-selector="comment"]');
    this._comments.forEach((comment) => {
      const deleteButton = comment.querySelector('[data-selector="delete-icon"]');
  
      deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
      return this.showDeleteDialog(event);});

    });
  }


  showDeleteDialog(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
     
    const comment = event.target.closest('[data-selector="comment"]');
    const dialog = comment.querySelector('[data-selector="dialog"]');
        
    console.log("In showDeleteDialog");
    this._handleEvent = this.hideDeleteDialog.bind(this, event, dialog)
    document.addEventListener('click', this._handleEvent);
 
  }

  hideDeleteDialog(event, dialog) {
      console.log("In hideDeleteDialog")
      // Not working
      document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleEvent)

  }
}

new CommentsBlock(document.getElementById("container"))
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body id="container">
    <p data-selector="comment">
      <button data-selector="delete-icon">
        delete1
      </button>
    </p>
     <p data-selector="comment">
      <button data-selector="delete-icon">
        delete2
      </button>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It must indeed be a copy of the function, as it was not working. I changed the code to assign `this._handleEvent = (event) => this.hideDeleteDialog(event, confirmDeleteDialog);` and this fixed the issue. Maybe you can add that to your answer, so I mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: Added potential solutions to my answer, Please see if it makes sense. BTW I doubt that mentioned change in your above comment will work :) as we are still creating new copies there.